# memcpy only data that's different

Tags: c

I have two very large arrays, and I want to memcpy only data that's different. The problem is if the second array has zeros in it, it will also copy zeros and overwrite the original's data. The problem is, zero is also a valid data item. What's an algorithm I can use to only memcpy data that's different?

What I've tried:

```
void *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char *dp = (char*) dest;
    const char *sp = (char*) src;
    while (n--)
    {
        if (*sp != 0)
            *dp = *sp;
        dp++;
        sp++;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    int test[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int test2[4] = {0, 0, 0, 5};
    my_memcpy(test, test2, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cout << test[i];
}
```

Comment: You would need to track modified data with some sort of auxilliary array and then use that to determine which ranges need to be copied.

Comment: @Paul Can you post an example?

Comment: By your description I take you intend to copy from the "second" array, and you don't want to copy the zeroes from it (you don't want to overwrite the "original's data"). You can't do this with the standard library's routines, you need to implement a loop for it with a conditional check for zero. If you are concerned about performance here, there are ways to perform this copy without conditionals.

Comment: How large? And how much of its contents would be modified? A `mmap` might help on certain cases cuz it comes with copy on write.

Comment: @JUbatian I have tried to write own memcpy that does `if (*src != 0)` but it didn't seem to make a difference. @starrify They're both one megabyte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems that need to be fixed.

The first problem is that `my_memcpy` checks and copies only one `char` at a time, but your stated requirement is only to copy non-zero `int` values. To understand why this is a problem consider the following two arrays.

```
int test [4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int modified[4] = { 512, 0, 0, 0 };
```

On a 32-bit little-endian system, the memory for these arrays looks like this

```
test      1 0 0 0   2 0 0 0   3 0 0 0   4 0 0 0
modified  0 2 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0
```

After calling `my_memcpy( test, modified, sizeof(test) )` the memory for the array will look like this

```
test      1 2 0 0   2 0 0 0   3 0 0 0   4 0 0 0
```

Note that `my_memcpy` will copy the `2` to the second position of the array, since `2` is the only non-zero `char` value in the modified array.  But that leaves the output array as

```
int test[4] = { 513, 2, 3, 4 };
```

which is not what you want.

---

The second problem is in the `main()` function. You're passing the value `4` as the size of the array.  Although 4 is the number of `int` values in the array, it is not the size of the array.  The array consists of 16 `char` values (on a 32-bit system). So you have to decide whether the size the you're passing to `my_memcpy` is the *size of the array in bytes*, or the *number of ints in the array*.

---

My suggested solution is to rewrite `my_memcpy` to use `int` pointers.

```
int *my_int_cpy( int *dest, const int *src, size_t count )
{
    while (count--)
    {
        if (*src != 0)
            *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    int test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int test2[] = {512, 0, 0, 5};
    int count = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);

    my_int_cpy( test, test2, count );
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf( "%d\n", test[i] );
}
```